# Verilog : Simple I2C read operation

Tags: verilog

I have written a program to read data from Microchip I2C EEPROM 24XX64. Initially I was able to get an acknowledge from the slave for command byte which indicates a READ operation. Perhaps, instead of data bits I was able to witness stL( write drive low signal) in model simulator. I would like to know the reason for this and what must be done to over come this signal.

Comment: Show us some waveforms and mark where you think things are going wrong!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please find the waveforms in the following link http://tinypic.com/r/2cr8qrb/6

Answer (score 3):

To read from an I2C slave, you usually have to *write* the register address first. The process to read is:

- START
- Device Address + WRITE
- Register Address (# of bytes depends on slave)
- REPEATED START
- Device Address + READ
- Slave ACKs
- Master Read bytes and NACKs when it's had enough
- STOP

Did you do a write to set up a register address for the read?

Comment: yeah. Data 16'b FFFF was written previously. I was about to perform a current read operation where in the data in current read was expected.

Comment: Hello, I just wrote a program for read as it was mentioned above but still I could see write drive 0 from the slave.